# Submiting a form via json/ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Here is my code

```
    function generate_clicked()
    {
        var txt_text_color = $('#txt_text_color').val();
        var url='process.php?';
        url+='txt_text_color='+encodeURIComponent(txt_text_color);


        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json; charset=x-user-defined");
          }
        }).done(function ( data ) {
            try{
                $('#preview').val(data.css);
                $('#my_iframe').srcdoc = data1;
                }
            catch(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            document.getElementById("my_iframe").src = data.live_preview_html_page;
        });

    }
```

This works for my purposes but if I added another form element I would tediousily have to add var example =$('....').val(); 
and
url+='example'+endcodeU.....

Which I will be having over 100 elements, then I would retreview them on process with

```
$txt_text_color = $_REQUEST['txt_text_color'];
```

My question is, how can I serialize this (I think that's what I need to do) so that I don't have to write those two varibles names each time I make a new form object.

I need to save get/post those varibles in process.php to use them.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm still learning.

Comment: you're basically trying to add form validation to your page?

Comment: Why not use .ajax()'s `data` functionality. You just provide with a javascript array/object and it'll take care of converting that into a POST body or GET query string for you.

Comment: Marc B can you please show me how I would write that?

No Jamie, I'm trying to pass variables then with those generate a custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Try form.serialize()
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Your code would look something like this:

```
function generate_clicked()
{
    var formData = $('#form').serialize();
    var url='process.php?';
    url+=formData;


    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json; charset=x-user-defined");
      }
    }).done(function ( data ) {
        try{
            $('#preview').val(data.css);
            $('#my_iframe').srcdoc = data1;
            }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        document.getElementById("my_iframe").src = data.live_preview_html_page;
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much exactly what I was trying to do!